# Creating Custom Folds For Caret CV

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation

I'm using the caret package to model and cross validate

```
model <- caret::train(mpg  ~ wt
                           + drat
                           + disp
                           + qsec
                           + as.factor(am),
                  data = mtcars,
                  method = "lm",
                  trControl = caret::trainControl(method = "cv",
                                                repeats=5,
                                                returnData =FALSE))
```

However, I'd like to pass the trainControl a custom set of indices relating to my folds. This can be done via IndexOut.

```
model <- caret::train(wt ~  + disp + drat,
                  data = mtcars,     
                  method = "lm",
                   trControl = caret::trainControl(method = "cv",
                                      returnData =FALSE,
                                      index = indicies$train,
                                      indexOut = indicies$test))
```

What I'm struggling with is that I only want to test on rows in mtcars where the `mtcars.am==0`. Thus the use of `createFolds` won't work because you can't add a criterion. Does anyone know of any other functions that allow indexing of rows into K-folds where a criterion of `mtcars.am==0` can be added in creating `indicies$test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help. I got there in the end by modifying the output from `createFolds` not the best example mtcars because it's such a small dataset but you get the idea:

```
folds<-caret::createFolds(mtcars,k=2)

indicies<-list()

#Create training folds
indicies$train<-lapply(folds,function(x) which(!1:nrow(mtcars) %in% x))

#Create test folds based output "folds" and with criterion added
indicies$test<-lapply(folds,function(x) which(1:nrow(mtcars) %in% x & mtcars[,"am"]==1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. Just feed the index with the desired row index.

```
index = list(which(mtcars$am == 0))

model <- caret::train(
    wt ~  +disp + drat,
    data = mtcars,
    method = "lm",
    trControl = caret::trainControl(
        method = "cv",
        returnData = FALSE,
        index = index
    )
)
```

index argument is a list so you can feed as many iterations as you want to that list by creating multiple nested list in the index.

Comment: Yes that's part way there but only gives 1 fold validation, I'm after something where you can still create multiple folds. To be honest I'm almost there myself now.